# How to get UITableViewCell's index from its UITextField?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios6

I have a UITextField in a custom cell inside table. I created new class **DataCell** which is subclass of UITableViewCell. Inside DataCell I created outlets for textfields and I also have method inside implementation file which uses 'editing did end' and I manipulate textField values there.

I am now wondering how to get rowIndex or number of the cell, as each time I click + button new custom cell is loaded on the table. If I get tag I always get same tag number regardless of the cell I selected.

Comment: Can't you set the tags of the text fields in cellForRowAtIndexPath to be indexPath.row? That's the way I usually see this kind of thing done.

Comment: I am newbie, how would set this specifically in interface builder?

Comment: You can't. It needs to be set in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:, because the cells get reused.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The text field passed to your delegate is a subview of the cell's `contentView`.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell*) textField.superview.superview; 
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: It is extremely fragile: You're relying on the fact that the textfield will always a) exist, b) be tied to a superview, c) be, in turn, tied to the cell.  Though, it works for this case.  You're both right.

Comment: Fragile in the sense that if the view hierarchy the cell changes, it will break

Comment: I get error saying tableView is not found in my class DataCell.

Comment: Your DataCell class *should not care* what index path it is in! This code should be in the table view controller.

Comment: Of course that code must the used in the table view controller. From inside the cell implementation you cannot know the index.

Comment: It depends on what point you need to know the cell that the UITextField is inside.  A UITableViewCell implementation itself will never know what index it is.  The code provided needs to be in the View Controller that contains the UITableView, so maybe in a UITextFieldDelegate method, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can use this logic when you are not sure of hierarchy between textfield and cell.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = nil;
UIView *parentView = textField.superview;
while(parentView) {
    if([parentView isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]) {
         cell = parentView;
         break;
    }
    parentView = parentView.superview;
} 

if(cell)
 NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:cell];
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the answer I have clear hierarchy however I get the error that tableView is not found on object DataCell

Answer (score 1):

Add tags to the text field in the tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: method. In this example, I have a custom cell with a label and a text field:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    RDCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.label1.text = self.theData[indexPath.row];
    cell.textField.tag = indexPath.row;
    return cell;
}
```

It sounds like you are maybe handling the end of editing in your custom cell class, but you might want to consider doing it in the table view controller instead, since that gives you easy access to the model, which I presume you are modifying with what the user types in the text field. If you do that, then you should connect the text field's delegate property up to the table view controller in IB.

Answer (score 0):

If we're accepting fragile answers then for the sake of contributing something new to the conversation:

```
CGRect rectInTableView =
    [tableView convertRect:textField.bounds fromView:textField];

NSUInteger indexOfCellContainingTextField =
    (NSUInteger)(rectInTableView.y / tableView.rowHeight);
```

Assumptions that make it fragile: (i) all rows are the same height; (ii) the height is set on the table view. If you haven't implemented `UITableViewDelegate -tableView:heightForRowAtIndexPath:` then both of those assumptions will hold true. You're also taking advantage of the fact that casting a positive float to an integer rounds down.

I would argue that although still not completely clear of assumptions, this is less fragile than Mundi's solution because it makes assumptions only about things you do directly control (ie, cell sizing) and not about things you don't (ie, the view hierarchy UIKit uses internally to present table views).